# Multiple spaces not showing up in comment code-blocks

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, comments

I wrote a solution to a code golf challenge that included the string `"....      ...."`. This exact number of dots and spaces was necessary for the solution to work.

Two users commented ([here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120216/loading-forever-windows-style/120321#comment296106_120321), [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120216/loading-forever-windows-style/120321#comment296324_120321)) on ways to golf it down. I tested their suggestions and found that they didn't work. Initially I thought the users were confused; Then I tried to write a comment:

> @User That doesn't work; Did you mean for the string to be `"....      ...."`?

And it rendered as:

> @User That doesn't work; Did you mean for the string to be `".... ...."`?

Is this intentional? If so, why? It has surely caused problems like this before. However, it looks like a bug to me. In posts, multiple spaces in backtick code blocks render as expected.

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior in the formatting sandbox: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/289798#comment960472_289798

Comment: I can also find unexpected behaviour with the character counter: https://puu.sh/vR0qt/db6bb5a889.png

Comment: This was fixed [almost 8 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30020/286591), but it seems to be back now. Since this seems to be a network wide problem, I have brought up the issue again [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296038/286591).

Comment: I use [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) to get around this issue when I must.

Comment: @ETHproductions `Does&nbsp;that&nbsp;work&nbsp;in&nbsp;code&nbsp;blocks?`

Comment: You can't use `&nbsp;`, you just have to copy-paste a raw non-breaking space from somewhere. I primarily use Windows, so I copy it from the Character Map program (it's the character after `~`). Example: `non-breaking    spaces  `

Comment: @ETHproductions Wow,▓just▓found▓my▓new▓favorite▓pastime.░That's░awesome.

Comment: `....      ....` alternating space and NBSP

Comment: I'm reading this on the mobile app and the spaces in the code blocks in the question are being "collapsed" too.

Comment: This appears to be `status      completed` now

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can make each character a different type of space; e.g. alternate normal and non-breaking spaces:

```
<space><nbsp><space><nbsp>...
```

---

@edit: As @ETHproductions points out, simply use all non-breaking space.

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods) lists several entry methods in various environments.

Comment: `....      ....` alternating space and NBSP

Comment: Or [just use all NBSP's](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12400/multiple-spaces-not-showing-up-in-comment-code-blocks#comment41830_12400)

Comment: `....      ....` All NBSP

Comment: @ETHproductions fair enough.  It didn't seem to work for me before when I tried, but now it looks good.

Comment: Do we really need to use a workaround - couldn't we just get a bugfix?

Comment: @MDXF it's now been reported here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296038/310400

Comment: @numbermaniac Yeah, because [DJMcMayhem posted that after reading this.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12400/multiple-spaces-not-showing-up-in-comment-code-blocks/12402?noredirect=1#comment41827_12400)

Comment: @MDXF, it's not really a bug: it's a design flaw in HTML. As such any "bug fix" implemented by the website is really a workaround rather than a bug fix.